# how to find radius of a circle if centre point is given?

Tags: java, android, geometry

I want to find the radius of a circle, to be drawn in the future. The data I have is the centre point (an X and Y co-ordinate).

```
CentrePoint(X,Y)
CentrePoint(1052.9414978027344,1434.042869567871)
```

Comment: You can't find the radius of a circle if the center point is the only information you have.

Comment: The correct answer is: `0 < r < infinity` where `r` is the radius of the circle. Really, having only the center of the circle says nothing about its radius. It can be any number greater than 0. Do you have any other information?

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle i have a point too. it contains a x and a y

Comment: Radius = SQRT((X1-X2)^2 + (Y1-Y2)^2)    the distance from the center point to a point on the circle.

Comment: @Grayson here X1 and Y1 can be any point of circle and X2 and Y2 are centre point... am i right?

Comment: @Android_Learner - that works, but since the differences are squared, it does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that the question is:

> How can I get the radius of a circle that I know the center of, based on a point related to that center, in Java or Dalvik (Android).

From a Math point of view, the distance between two points in the same plane is the square root of the sum from the power of two from each side in a triangle:

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotenuse):

[image: Hypotenuse]

So:

```
private double getRadius(Point a, Point circleCenter) {
    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.abs(a.x) - Math.abs(circleCenter.x), 2) + Math.pow(Math.abs(a.y) - Math.abs(circleCenter.y), 2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot i got it :)

Comment: If this answered your question, then select the `v` symbol on the left, near the arrows, as this will mark the question as answered. If this did not answer your question, edit your question and try to give more details on what your problem is/was. Welcome to stackoverflow and please read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to get better answers

Comment: @Bonatti  `v` isn't even close to `✓`.

Comment: @bcsb1001 too lazy to look at the encode char list to find such a non common symbol =/.... for all purposes, lets assume its a `✓` with less effort... like `v` or (from faaaarrrr `. `)